# Create two Side Navs in materialize css

Tags: materialize

I want to have two side navs which are triggered from different directions of the screen using materialize css. How should I initialize the two different side navs as I have to use different options for them?

```
$('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

How should I initialize another sidenav, its because I want to have different options for them? 
I have tried using a different class name which didn't work.
Please suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, by specifying a separate class my other side nav.
It seems that the `class sidenav` has to present for the sidenav to function properly. So I created a class and solved my problem as

```
$('.sidenav.my-side-nav-1').sidenav(options1);
```

and similarly I have my other sidenav as

```
$('.sidenav.my-side-nav').sidenav(options2);
```